# How to enable ssl/crypto in Erlang/YAWS

Tags: ssl, cryptography, erlang, yaws

I am getting the following error while running "configure" on yaws-2.0.4:

```
Check Erlang environment & applications
checking for erl... /usr/local/bin/erl
checking for erlc... /usr/local/bin/erlc
checking for escript... /usr/local/bin/escript
checking for dialyzer... /usr/local/bin/dialyzer
checking for ct_run... /usr/local/bin/ct_run
checking for erlc... /usr/local/bin/erlc
checking for erl... /usr/local/bin/erl
checking for Erlang/OTP root directory... /usr/local/lib/erlang
checking for Erlang/OTP library base directory... /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib
checking for Erlang/OTP ERTS version... 8.1
checking for Erlang/OTP ERTS directory... /usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-8.1
checking for Erlang/OTP release... 19
checking for Erlang/OTP library installation base directory... ${ERLANG_LIB_DIR}
checking for Erlang/OTP 'yaws' library installation subdirectory... ${ERLANG_LIB_DIR}/yaws-2.0.4
checking for Erlang/OTP 'yapp' library installation subdirectory... ${ERLANG_LIB_DIR}/yapp-0.4.2
checking for Erlang/OTP 'kernel' library subdirectory... /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-5.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'kernel' library version... 5.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'stdlib' library subdirectory... /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'stdlib' library version... 3.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'sasl' library subdirectory... /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-3.0.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'sasl' library version... 3.0.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'erts' library subdirectory... /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erts-8.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'erts' library version... 8.1
checking for Erlang/OTP 'compiler' library subdirectory... /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/compiler-7.0.2
checking for Erlang/OTP 'compiler' library version... 7.0.2
checking for Erlang/OTP 'crypto' library subdirectory... not found
checking for Erlang/OTP 'crypto' library version... not found
configure: error: "crypto" Erlang application not found.
```

but I am trying to enable the SSL for otp_src_19.1, but it gives the following info:

For executing `./configure --with-ssl`    in Mac:

```
*********************************************************************
**********************  APPLICATIONS DISABLED  **********************
*********************************************************************

crypto         : No usable OpenSSL found
odbc           : ODBC library - header check failed
ssh            : No usable OpenSSL found
ssl            : No usable OpenSSL found

*********************************************************************
*********************************************************************
**********************  APPLICATIONS INFORMATION  *******************
*********************************************************************

wx             : wxWidgets not found, wx will NOT be usable

*********************************************************************
*********************************************************************
**********************  DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION  ******************
*********************************************************************

documentation  : 
                 fop is missing.
                 Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.

*********************************************************************
```

Comment: Have a look at the [requirements for building Erlang with OpenSSL](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#id61398).

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I set the path of SSL  then its threw.. ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/

Comment: but when i run YAWS... yaws starting crypto.. and falling on error and gets terminated.
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Oct-2016::23:13:39 ===
Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:
"load_failed, Failed to load NIF library: 'dlopen(/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.7.1/priv/lib/crypto.so, 2): Symbol not found: _EVP_aes_128_cbc

Answer (score -2):

You must install required OpenSSL version from here: `https://www.openssl.org/source/`. Just download the source from here and reading `INSTALL` readme, you can install OpenSSL on your OS. Check OpenSSL version using `openssl version -a` command, after installation.